# Finding the points where a tangent plane is parallel to another plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am supposed to find the points where the tangent plane to $z = 8-17x^2-19y^2 $is parallel to the plane $78x+52y+68z=96$

I've calculated that the gradient of $z$ is $[-34x,-38x,1$], and I think that the gradient will be perpendicular to the points that I'm looking for, but I've got no idea what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you got your gradient. This would be my way.
We take the gradient of the implicit surface defined by
$17x^2+19y^2+z = 8$.

It has gradient $\langle34x, 38y, 1\rangle$ (The gradient should depend on $x$ and $y$!).

This gives the normal of the surface.
In the next step you would want it to be parallel to the normal of the plane $\langle78, 52, 68\rangle$ (planes with parallel normals are parallel!).

Comment: Oops, the gradient apparently didn't paste correctly from Maple. So there should be some k such that [34x,38y,1] = [78k, 52k, 68k]? So for 68k = 1, k = 1/68, and then I can solve for x and y?

Comment: indeed! draw both in maple and see if it makes sense. I'm a bit rusty.